# not able to change item of carousel scroller with button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, carousel, flutter-dependencies

i have done carousel scrollbar for items array but when i am pressing icon button left or right then i am not able to change item i can change the animated dots with button but the items is not changing with that

```
Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          children: [
                            Stack(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              children: [
                                SingleChildScrollView(
                                  child: CarouselSlider(
                                      carouselController:
                                          buttonCarouselController,
                                      items: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                              9, 9, 9, 0),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Pending',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Heat No',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      '0C126',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'PRC No',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      'IB0975',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Die No',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      'M5050',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Part',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Front Y Slide Casting-LCB',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Grade',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      'A356T6',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Quantity',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      '4',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                        6, 6, 6, 0),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Issue Date and Time',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      '31-07-2021',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                              9, 9, 9, 0),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Pending2',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Heat No',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      '0C126',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                                        6, 6, 6, 0),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Text(
                                                      'Issue Date and Time',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                    Text(
                                                      '31-07-2021',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 17,
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.w900),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                      options: CarouselOptions(
                                        height: 310,
                                        // aspectRatio: 1.1,
                                        viewportFraction: 0.95,
                                        initialPage: 0,
                                        enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                                        autoPlay: true,
                                        autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 4),
                                        autoPlayAnimationDuration:
                                            Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                                        autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                                        enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                        enlargeFactor: 0.3,
                                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                        onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            activeIndexSub = index;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      )),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                  child: AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                                    activeIndex: activeIndexSub,
                                    count: 2,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Flexible(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      buttonCarouselController.previousPage();
                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                                      color: Colors.amber,
                                      size: 30,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Flexible(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      buttonCarouselController.nextPage();
                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                                      color: Colors.amber,
                                      size: 30,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
```

i want to do that when i press button the animatedsmoothindicator will change but also able to scroll item by pressing button